# Write a condition that defines the spherical surface of center $(-1,1,1)$ that is tangent to the plane $\{z=1\}$

Tags: calculus, geometry

> [image]
>
> Point $A$ has coordinates $(-1,1,1)$
>
> Write a condition that defines the spherical surface of centre
>   $(-1,1,1)$ that is tangent to the plane $\{z=1\}$

How do I do this? I know the equation to the sphere has to be $(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2 = ??$, how do I make it tangent?

Comment: What’s the distance from $A$ to the plane?

Comment: @amd How do I calculate that?

Answer (score 1):

If a sphere is tangent to a plane, then the distance of its center to the plane is equal to its radius. In your case, the radius is 1 unit.

Comment: How do I know the distance of its center to the plane? The plane has many points, so I assume this distance is between the center and a specific point, which one?

Comment: @MarkRead The distance of a point to a plane is particularly easy to attain. The specific point you're reffering to is the one obtained by the intersection of a perpendicular line to the plane passing through the center. In your case, the line will be the one passing through (-1,1,1) parallel to the z-axis. If that is not clear, you will need to tell me more about what you know.

Comment: @MarkRead It’s the minimum distance between points on the plane and the point not on the plane, which will occur when the segment joining them is perpendicular to the plane.

Comment: @Daniel I don't know much about this, to be honest. Ok so you need a perpendicular line, how do you get that line?